# Bind template to a model programmatically using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given an HTML template

```
<div class="info">
    <div class="title"><a href="property-detail.html">{{title}}</a></div>
    <div class="location">{{location}}</div>
    <div class="property-info clearfix">
        <div class="area"><i class="icon icon-normal-cursor-scale-up"></i>{{size}}<sup>2</sup></div>
        <div class="bedrooms"><i class="icon icon-normal-bed"></i>{{bedrooms}}</div>
        <div class="bathrooms"><i class="icon icon-normal-shower"></i>{{bathrooms}}</div>
    </div><div class="price">{{price}}</div>
    <div class="link">
        <a href="{{details}}">View more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a model that fits this template (that is, has all the fields: title, location, price, etc.). I am looking for a way to programmatically bind the template to the model and then push the rendered results to an array. In pseudo-code I am looking to do something like that:

```
var boxes= [];
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var results = bind(template, items[i]);
    boxes.push(results);
}
```

Where items is an array of items which i got from the database or any other source, and bind is basically the function that is responsible to populate the template with the model.

It makes sense to use a directive. Not sure how to do that though.

Any idea if and how it can be done using Angular?

Comment: Do you want the bound template to end up in the DOM? Or do you just want it in the array for later use?

Comment: This looks like you are defining what a directive is for...

Comment: @bmceldowney I would like to use the array later on. Specifically, i would like to feed it to a map widget that i have and the widget requires an array of all the boxes (which are attached to points on the map)

Comment: @PSL yes it seems like something that can be done with a directive, but how do i take the results and push them to an array instead of adding them to the page by applying the directive name?

Comment: You will have an ng-repeat on the directive. ex:- `<my-dir data-item="item" ng-repeat="item in boxes"></my-dir>` and you would need to put boxes on the scope... If your template url needs to be dynamic based on some static situation then you can as well use templateUrl as a function that returns a templateName.. based on some attributes on the element

Comment: @DavidBarel Probably i misunderstood can you show a demo of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @PSL not sure I understand how to take the results and push them to an array. Also, my challenge is to push the rendered template (1 per item) into the boxes array. Boxes array will be delivered to a widget which contains it own logic.

Comment: @DavidBarel `the rendered template (1 per item) into the boxes array` Why do you bother? it is directive's responsibility to render the template . You will just bind the data from your controller... ie results will just be array of items. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61632/discussion-between-david-barel-and-psl).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you never want to manipulate DOM in anything other than a directive. But why be dogmatic about it? If you really need a compiled template in a string format (for 3rd party widget consumption or such like) then you can put together a service similar to the following:

```js
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, templateCompiler) {
  var boxes = [];
  var data = [{
      title: 'test',
      location: 'location!',
      size: 40,
      bedrooms: 'yes',
      bathrooms: 'uncertain',
      price: 'if you have to ask...',
      details: 'indeterminate'
  },{
      title: 'test2',
      location: 'somewhere',
      size: 'a woman never tells',
      bedrooms: 3.14,
      bathrooms: null,
      price: 1400,
      details: 'forthcoming'
  }];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var results = templateCompiler.bind(data[i]);
    boxes.push(results);
  }
  
  $scope.boxes = boxes;
})

angular.module('app').service('templateCompiler', function ($compile, $templateCache, $rootScope) {
  var service = {}
  var template = $templateCache.get('boxTemplate');
  var scope;
  
  this.bind = function (data) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    angular.extend(scope, data);
    var link = $compile(template);
    var content = link(scope);
    scope.$apply();
    return content.html();
  };  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="boxTemplate">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="title"><a href="property-detail.html">{{title}}</a></div>
        <div class="location">{{location}}</div>
        <div class="property-info clearfix">
            <div class="area"><i class="icon icon-normal-cursor-scale-up"></i>{{size}}<sup>2</sup></div>
            <div class="bedrooms"><i class="icon icon-normal-bed"></i>{{bedrooms}}</div>
            <div class="bathrooms"><i class="icon icon-normal-shower"></i>{{bathrooms}}</div>
        </div><div class="price">{{price}}</div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href="{{details}}">View more</a>
    </div>
  </div></script>

  <!-- TO PROVE YOU GET THE DESIRED OUTPUT -->
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">{{boxes}}</div>
</div>
```

You also might consider wrapping your map widget in a directive.